# How to create persistent object in Java

Tags: java

Can you give me an example of creating persistent object in Java. thanks

Comment: Your question is very ambigious, please add more detail to get better answers.

Comment: Can you clarify? There are a lot of ways to persist an object. From writing it to a database to serializing it and saving it to a file.

Answer (score 4):

`public class MyClass implements Serializable`

Answer (score 4):

Depending on *where* you want to persist the object, take a look at:

- JPA, for relational database
- JDO (Java Data Objects, a more general persistence mechanism)
- JAXB - XML serialization
- `java.io.Serializable` or protobuf - binary serialization